# is Chrome mini-info bar for PWA install only, or available for native install as well?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, native, progressive-web-apps, prompt

information in this link seems to suggest that I can have the mini-info bar show to prompt the user for a native app install:

[Native App Install Prompt](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native)

however it never shows up. I made sure that my manifest complies with all the conditions, and can see the 'beforeinstallprompt' being fired, but still the banner never shows up.

Comment: Are you also serving your site over https? You don't have the app already installed on your device and you have visited your site twice and used it for 30seconds?

Comment: @Shnigi Yea doing all of those, and 'beforeinstallprompt' event is being fired which as indication that all the criteria have been met, but still no banners ..

Comment: And just to make sure you have tried this on actual server / domain and not in localhost? I think sometimes it doesn't work on localhost or you have to do proxy at least.

Comment: yea actual server, im guessing the documentation was in part copied from PWA documentation, which doesn't apply to native install prompt

Comment: I have never tried native app install prompt myself so can't really tell what is wrong. I have done a lot of testing with PWA though and the banner works there without problems. Thats all I can say :/

Comment: yea for PWA it shows up. thanks for the help anyways